# If model has a customized manager, how can I use default?

Tags: python, django

If model defined with custom manager, but I need to query database with default Django manager `django.db.models.manager.Manager` - how can I do that?

**UPDATE**
Main issue is that I don't have access to the code, and the model does not have standard manager available, only customized one.

Comment: Is this a model that you have implemented, or a third-party one? If you've implemented it, you should probably keep your custom manager in a different class attribute instead of replacing the default one in `objects`. You _can_ instantiate a new default manager, but since you _do_ need to use the default, why not just keep it there?

Comment: You can also add your custom manager to `objects` but add an instance of the default manager to another attribute, like `default_manager` or `unfiltered` or whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

Keep your custom managers *after* the default manager. Like this:

```
# Then hook it into the Book model explicitly.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    dahl_objects = DahlBookManager() # The Dahl-specific manager.
```

You are free to use both `Book.objects.<...>` and `Book.dahl_objects.<...>` for filtering. However, there are a few things to note with managers, esp. default ones. From [managers documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/):

> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a class as the “default” Manager, and several parts of Django (including dumpdata) will use that Manager exclusively for that model. As a result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding get_queryset() results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.

A reminder which has caused me headaches in the past:

> Do not filter away any results in this type of manager subclass
>
> One reason an automatic manager is used is to access objects that are related to from some other model. In those situations, Django has to be able to see all the objects for the model it is fetching, so that anything which is referred to can be retrieved.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to address [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864115/change-manager-for-django-models-objects-with-a-decorator) question? It's essentially looking for the opposite behavior where we _want_ to override the default `objects` with our own manager. The tricky part is how can this be done with a decorator?