# Change manager for django model's '.objects' with a decorator

Tags: django

I am trying to write a decorator for changing django models' managers like the following:

```
def custom_manager(*args):
    class CustomManager(models.Manager):
        pass
    def wrapper(cls):
        cls.add_to_class('objects', CustomManager())
        return cls
    return wrapper

@custom_manager()
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

the problem seems to be that `objects` attribute is already taken by the default manager, and it must be removed from the model first. Simply setting cls.objects = CustomManager() inside the decorator does not work too.

Everything works fine if I use some unused attribute name (i.e. not `objects`), but I want to replace exactly the `objects` attribute to make all apps (e.g. DjangoAdmin etc) use this custom manager.

So is there a way to correctly remove the default manager from the model or fix it some other way?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am stuck on the exact same question in Django 3.2

Comment: Why do this? A decorator will take you one line and a `objects = CustomManager()` will again take you one line, writing a decorator for this is really overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
def custom_manager(cls):
  class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    pass

  cls.objects= CustomManager()
  return cls


@custom_manager()
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: It has no effect.