# How do I prevent a manager added in an abstract model from becoming the default?

Tags: python, django, django-models

We frequently add `soft_deleted` fields to our models in order to mark them as deleted without actually deleting them in case the user / we have made a mistake and we want to undo it, and for other record keeping reasons.

I wanted to commonize this by adding an abstract model class with that field and a manager to get undeleted objects on it (and some other not-relevant-here methods):

```
from django.db.models import Manager, Model


class UndeletedObjectsManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model._default_manager.filter(soft_deleted=False)


class SoftDeletableModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    soft_deleted = BooleanField(default=False)

    undeleted_objects = UndeletedObjectsManager()
```

However, when I use it, depending I think on MRO order, sometimes the `undeleted_objects` manager ends up as the default manager, rather than `objects` which is defined on another abstract model class, meaning that e.g. reverse many-to-many managers don't work properly (they filter by `soft_deleted`).

I know that I could set `default_manager_name` in all the subclass models, but that would be repeating myself a lot and defeat part of the point of the refactor.

Is there any other way I can prevent this from happening, and guarantee that `undeleted_objects` won't be picked as the default manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django interprets [the first manager instance it finds on the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._default_manager) as the default manager, so try:

```
class SoftDeletableModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    soft_deleted = BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = models.Manager()
    undeleted_objects = UndeletedObjectsManager()
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it hides the `objects` manager which is created in another abstract model further down the MRO, and which I can't generally recreate in this model.

Comment: Guess this is hard to tell as i dont know how your chain of ineritance looks like, maybe you can post some code?

Comment: Hmm, guess you're right, I could add `objects` as a default manager and then make sure `SoftDeletableModel` is always put at the bottom of the inheritance chain, so it will be overridden. Not perfect, since it's annoying having to worry about the ordering, but perfection might not be achievable...

Comment: Any thoughts on how to address [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864115/change-manager-for-django-models-objects-with-a-decorator) question? It's essentially looking for the opposite behavior where we _want_ to override the default `objects` with our own manager. The tricky part is how can this be done with a decorator?